# Django template variable does not show up

Tags: django, object, templates, variables

for some reason im unable to display the comments of a category_request and i have now idea why, is smb. maybe able to have an eye on that, praticaly i should work but i dont see the mistake here.
as far as i see I'm using category_request_comment from the view to get a releated comment objects from a category_request... any idea?

Template Snippet:

```
{% for category_request_comment in category_request_comments %}
    <div class="comment">
        <p>{{ category_request_comment.content|readmore:15 }}</p>

        {% if category_request_comment.content.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                <a>Comment by: {{ category_request_comment.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Commented at: {{ category_request_comment.published_date }}</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if request.user == category_request_comment.author %}
            <a class="commentoption" href="{% url 'comment_edit' pk=category_request_comment.pk %}">Edit</a><a> | </a>
            <a class="commentoption" href="{% url 'comment_delete' pk=category_request_comment.pk %}">Delete</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def category_request_detail(request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    list_category_request = CategoryRequests.objects.get_queryset().filter(id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    paginator = Paginator(list_category_request, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    category_request_comment = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'myproject/category_request_detail.html', {'category_request': category_request, 'category_request_comment': category_request_comment})
```

views.py (only for Reference)

```
def category_request_comment_new(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CategoryRequestsCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
            requests_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            requests_comment.author = request.user
            requests_comment.published_date = timezone.now()
            requests_comment.category_request = category_request
            requests_comment.save()
            return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=requests_comment.category_request.pk)
    else:
        form = CategoryRequestsCommentForm()
        return render(request, 'myproject/comment_new.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^categories/requests/$', myproject_views.category_request_list, name='category_request_list'),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't passed in a context variable named `category_request_comments`. Check your view function. Did you mean to add an "s"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is looking for an object called `category_request_comments`, but you have not sent anything with that name to the template.

Comment: Thanks for this small hint :D

Answer (score 0):

```
def category_request_detail(request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    list_comments = CategoryRequests_Comment.objects.get_queryset().filter(category_request_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    paginator = Paginator(list_comments, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    comments = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request, 'myproject/category_request_detail.html', {'category_request': category_request, 'comments': comments})
```